# decltype of a class member variable, is it forbidden? Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I can write

```
int a;
decltype(a) b;
```

but my compiler (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, `cl` Version 16.00.40219.01) forbid me

```
class A
{
   int a;
   decltype(a) b;// error C2327: 'A::a' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
};
```

Also Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008 11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2 gives a similar error.

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 7: error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a
          specific object
     decltype(a) b;
              ^
```

What is the rationale for this behaviour?

Comment: Works with gcc 4.7, so maybe it's a bug.

Comment: @evnu Thank you for your test. I should check the standard in order to say it's a bug.

Comment: @evnu g++ (Debian 4.6.1-15) 4.6.1 compiles it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that is valid. Within unevaluated operands (operands of `decltype`, `sizeof`, `noexcept`, ...) you can name nonstatic data members also outside of member functions.

Those compilers you tried just don't support this feature yet.

Comment: I.e. your compiler only implements part of C++11 (Relaxed rules for naming unevaluated operands and `decltype` are both new).

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb
Hello, do you have any reference to the standard? (chapter numbers or the like)