# C++11 decltype of member

Tags: c++, c++11

Why can't I do this:

```
class Foo {
  void fn();
  using fn_t = decltype(fn); //call to non-static member function without an object argument
};
```

But I can do

```
class Foo {
  static void fn();
  using fn_t = decltype(fn);
};
```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7928123/2556973) claims:

> Within unevaluated operands (operands of decltype, sizeof, noexcept, ...) you can name nonstatic data members also outside of member functions

Comment: Note that a function is not a data member.

Comment: `decltype` takes an expression. `fn` by itself is not an expression.

Comment: @dyp But can it appear on its own? I seem to recall there's something about how a member function name can appear only in a function call, or in `&ClassName::FunctionName`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think it may not appear in this context. It's either `&Foo::fn` or `fn()`, but it is an expression. [expr.prim.general]/13

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ya I jsut checked the standard, you're correct. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) said it could also take an *entity* - that threw me off I guess. Is there anyway I can do what I'm trying to do though?

Comment: @dyp but I can *decltype* an arbitrary function outside the class scope - I don't understand why they would then restrict usage for member functions

Comment: @quantdev from second sample I guess he looks for `decltype(&Foo::fn)` but shorter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354841/decltype-and-member-function-not-pointer-type

Comment: @dyp looks like you had the answer first!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fn` is a valid *id-expression* denoting a non-static member function. §5.1.1 [expr.prim.general]/p13 (footnote omitted):

> An *id-expression* that denotes a non-static data member or non-static
>   member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access (5.2.5) in which the object expression refers to the member’s class or a class derived from that
>     class, or
> - to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), or
> - if that *id-expression* denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

§7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]/p4:

> The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5).

Since `decltype` is not one of the few contexts in which an *id-expression* denoting a non-static member function may be used, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Ohh because its not a data member .. its a member function. I see. Thanks for the reference! I couldnt find it

Comment: How does one become that knowledgeable with the standard?

Comment: @user70869 By referring to it often, whenever in doubt, for a few years.